# Как построить график в Python, используя данные из XLSX-файла?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

Есть данные в XLSX-файле (можно в CSV), скачанные из Google SpreadSheets. Данные записаны в два столбика, вот так:

```
60,0633 01.08.2017
59,8454 02.08.2017
60,5819 03.08.2017
60,7503 04.08.2017
60,3281 05.08.2017
```

Вопрос: как на Python'e построить график с двумя осями на основе этих данных?
Какие библиотеки использовать?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Воспользуйтесь модулем [Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/10min.html):

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib
matplotlib.style.use('ggplot')

# подставьте ссылку на ваш файл или полный путь к файлу на вашем компьютере...    
url = 'https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0Ak1ecr7i0wotdGJmTURJRnZLYlV3M2daNTRubTdwTXc&output=csv'

df = pd.read_csv(url, names=['val','date'], index_col=[1], decimal=',',
                 parse_dates=True, dayfirst=True)

df.plot()
#plt.savefig('d:/temp/out.png')
plt.show()
```

[Документация (с примерами) по визуализации в Pandas](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/visualization.html)

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: В качестве ссылки поставил путь к CSV-файлу на компьютере. Заработало. Но отображается не корректно. Он словно в первом столбике разделяет целую и дробную части числа по разным осям. Как быть?

Comment: Не к тому путь указал.

Answer (score 1):

Можно использовать библиотеки [Pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) и [Pyplot](https://matplotlib.org/users/pyplot_tutorial.html). Примерно так:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

table = pd.read_excel('data.xlsx')
x = table.values[:, 0]
y = table.values[:, 1]

plt.figure(figsize=(15, 7))
plt.plot(x, y)
plt.show()
```